# SQLDataReader returns null even when data exist

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqldatareader

I'm suddenly experiencing issues with obtaining data from the MS SQL DB using the `SQLDataReader`. The problem is that it's only happening for one specific table and the exactly the same approach works for all other tables.

This table contains **~24.000 rows** of data and I'm obtaining only column `ID` which is a `nvarchar(max)` in DB and I'm mapping it to string.

When I use the SQL command, I get `DBNull`. The most interesting thing is that if I add `TOP` command to the query, it suddenly works and return all rows.

**This doesn't work and return `null`:**

`SELECT [ID] FROM [Table]`
**This works and return all data:**
`SELECT TOP(25000) [ID] FROM [Table]`
**This is my code:**

```
string sql = $@"SELECT {columnList} FROM [{TableName}] {whereString} {orderByString}";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var i = 0;
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            {
                var value = reader.GetValue(i);
                ret.Add((T)value);
            }
        }
    }
}

conn.Close();
}

return ret;
```

Does anyone know why is this happening and why usage of `TOP` suddenly fixes it?

How can I fix this without using the `TOP` because it makes no sense to use it to get all rows.

Comment: If you load the data in a datatable using the SqlDataAdapter how many rows count do you see ?

Comment: @Steve I have tested it with SqlDataAdapter and "dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count" contains correct number of rows even when I don't use TOP.

Comment: What is `ret` in this case, and where do you see `DBNull`? `reader.GetValue` can produce a `DBNull` if the source column is `NULL` (that is, there are IDs in your table that are `NULL`).

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and try query in SSMS.  Either there is no data or the credentials aren't working.  You can check the log files in SSMS in explorer under management tab to see if there were any errors when you ran the c# code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ```ret``` is an empty List which I created before. I just add the results in it. The error is thrown at the line ```ret.Add((T)value);``` because T == string and error states that it's unable to cast DBNull to string. ```reader.GetValue(0)``` returns DBNull and ```reader.GetValue(1)``` and above says index out of range. There are no NULL IDs in the table.

Comment: @jdweng I tried the query is SSMS and it works just fine, with and without TOP. It's not credentials, because I run about 15 SELECT queries using this method and only this one doesn't work. Also if it would be credentials issue, the TOP would not fix it.

Comment: Just for sanity's sake, could you try `SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [ID] IS NULL` in SSMS anyway? Also, could you print the actual contents of `sql` to verify the query is what you think it is? Barring a very odd bug in the client or a non-deterministic view (i.e. `Table` isn't really a table), retrieving a `DBNull` where there is no `NULL` should be impossible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I guess you resolved it. There was indeed one record with ID NULL. It was the very last record. I have removed it and now it works. One thing is still not clear to me though. Why did usage of TOP get rid of this error? The null value woulc still be there even if TOP would change the order of rows, I would hit it sooner or later, but I did not.

Comment: Well, there the assumption is that your table indeed has no more than 25000 rows. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table]` should confirm that. Also, of course, `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is non-deterministic, though that doesn't matter if you're selecting more rows than the table contains and you're reading all rows.